# How to get a single bolded element using css selectors

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium webdriver and python for testing. I have a clickable list of elements in a table. The ones that are in bold have not been selected yet and I would like to select the first of these when I run my test, but can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The css structure in the table is:

```
tbody tr td a span.xm b ( if bolded ) ( the first of these is what I want )
tbody tr td a span.xm ( if not )
```

I tried:

```
tbody tr:first-of-type td a span.ts > b
```

which unfortunately selects ALL of the bolded elements. Can someone advise me what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the python equivalent of this java:

```
    findAll(By.cssSelector("tbody tr:first-of-type td a span.ts > b"))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that webdriver has the option of selecting for example find_element_by_css_selector and find_elements_by_css_selector which return a single element or list respectively. In my case I can use the former . http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html